# iCloud Music Library and Apple Music subscriber - mass delete all local music files from iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, music

I enabled iCloud Music Library and subscribed to Apple Music.

I have iPhone with 16 GB and wish to delete all local music files, to free up space for other stuff. Before iCloud Music I would "not sync" my music files and then they get deleted from iPhone.

[image]

[image]

With a search engine I found how to to delete songs in Music app. Bud sadly I need to delete every artist individually. I have about 600 different artists and albums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open settings
2. Tap general
3. Tap Storage and iCloud Storage
4. Under Storage, find music.
5. Swipe left where it says "All Songs"
6. Press delete.